# Getting the values of UI elements with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm developing a simple user interface with Tkinter. I have some checkbuttons, entries and I should setup a button to save them all in a file.
This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import json, sys

class Window(Frame):
    def load_config(self,obs,wav):
         d = json.load(open('config.txt','r'))
         self.conf_dict = d[obs][wav]

    def __init__(self,master,observatory,wavelength):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.load_config(observatory,wavelength)
        r = 0
        for k,v in self.conf_dict.items():
            r += 1
            self.l = Label(master, text=k+':')
            self.l.grid(row=r,column=0,padx=10, pady=5)
            if isinstance(v,bool):
                self.c = Checkbutton(master)
                self.c.grid(row=r,column=1,padx=10,pady=5)
            else:
                self.e = Entry(master)
                self.e.insert(END,str(v))
                self.e.grid(row=r,column=1,padx=10, pady=5)
        self.b = Button(master,text='Save',command=save_callback)

    def save_callback(self):
        # save new config file with json

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = Window(root,sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
    root.mainloop()
```

Best idea would be to modify the values of `conf_dict` directly and save the dict in `save_callback`. How can I do this? I need some way to get the ID of the button or to link them to the dict.

NOTE: I tried with `self.c = Checkbutton(master,var=self.conf_dict[k])`but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you need to grab the value of the checkbox? so to check to see if it is checked or not? Im getting confused on what exactly you are asking for.

Comment: Yes of course I need the values of the checkbox. What is not clear?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
class Window(Frame):

    def load_config(self,obs,wav):
         d = json.load(open('config.txt','r'))
         self.conf_dict = d[obs][wav]

    def save_callback(self,d):
        for k,v in l.items():
            print(k,v.get())
        # save new config file with json

    def __init__(self,master,observatory,wavelength):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        self.load_config(observatory,wavelength)
        self.elements = {}
        for k,v in self.conf_dict.items():
            l = Label(master, text=k+':')
            l.grid(row=len(self.elements),column=0,padx=10, pady=5)
            if isinstance(v,bool):
                self.elements[k] = IntVar()
                self.elements[k].set(int(v))
                c = Checkbutton(master, var=self.elements[k])
                c.grid(row=len(self.elements)-1,column=1,padx=10,pady=5)
            else:
                self.elements[k] = Entry(master)
                self.elements[k].insert(END,str(v))
                self.elements[k].grid(row=len(self.elements)-1,column=1,padx=10,pady=5)
        self.b = Button(master,text='Save',
                 command=(lambda new_dict=self.elements:self.save_callback(new_dict)))
        self.b.grid(row=len(self.elements),column=1,padx=10,pady=5)
```